# Chrome Dev Tools - Filter out xhrs from background worker

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to troubleshoot some UI issues that I've been having that I think are tied to XHR requests that I'm making on the main thread.  But when I look at the network tab, I see a ton of my background worker requests and it becomes really hard to see exactly which request came from where.

Is there any way to filter the network request so that I can see if the request was initiated from a background worker (and if so, which one) or the main thread?

I added the "initiator" column to my network tab, but it just says "Other".

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: By "background worker" you mean a web worker (`window.Worker`), right?

Comment: Yes, sorry for not being more specific.